# Invalid schema document passed to AbstractDataBinding while deploy web service on tomcat

Tags: rest, soap, deployment, tomcat7, cxf

Here is my problem, i'm trying to deploy a web service on a tomcat7, 
My web service contains a REST service and a SOAP service with CXF.
I don't think that it is a problem about dependencies but i linked my pom.xml because i'm not sure of this. I really have no idea about this error some help will be welcome ! 
Here is the stacktrace :

```
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sms': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid schema document passed to AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument, not in W3C schema namespace: schema
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5284)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid schema     document passed to AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument, not in W3C schema namespace: schema
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:369)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:537)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1608)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid schema document passed to AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument, not in W3C schema namespace: schema
at org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument(AbstractDataBinding.java:109)
at org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument(AbstractDataBinding.java:95)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:388)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:478)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:690)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:540)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:252)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:454)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
... 34 more
```

Here is my pom.xml :
**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cxf.version>2.7.3</cxf.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
    <jaxws-rt.version>2.2.8</jaxws-rt.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxws-rt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- CXF dependencies -->

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>${cxf.version}</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>${jaxws-rt.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

My web.xml :
**web.xml**

`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>



<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

`

My ApplicationContext.xml :
**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/beans"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://www.cxf.apache.org/bindings/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
>
<!-- JAX-RS -->
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.chronolink.smsplatform.services"          />
<jaxrs:server id="messageServices" address="/MessageServices">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="messageServiceImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>
<!-- JAX-WS -->
<jaxws:endpoint id="sms"
    implementor="fr.chronolink.smsplatform.controller.SmsServiceController"
    address="/sms" />
<jaxws:endpoint id="admin"
    implementor="fr.chronolink.smsplatform.controller.AdminServiceController"
    address="/admin" />
<bean id="messageServiceImpl"
    class="fr.chronolink.smsplatform.services.rest.impl.MessageServiceImpl" />
<bean id="messageDao" class="fr.chronolink.smsplatform.services.rest.daos.MessageDao" />
</beans>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Would you care to tell us which libraries were conflicting? Thanks! Gerard

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Weblogic 10. In my case it was the clash between XmlNamespace.class and Schema.class classes from two jars: rt.jar and jaxb-impl.jar (so the XmlNamespace of the Schema could not be found).
Check whether jaxb-impl.jar is deployed on your server and if yes - try to deploy without it and see whether it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

do you have other applications in your Tomcat7?

I ask because I have the same problem with tomcat webprofile 1.7.1, but only if certain applications are started before the victim application.  I have not yet found the exact cause, but the workaround is to make sure in which order they are started.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on, it was because tomcat had some dependencies that maven wanted to bring into my webapp. 
Then , there was a conflict between tomcat's libraries and my war's libraries.

So make sure to handle this when you are compiling your webapp that there is no versioning problems about jars that your application needs and what is already on your tomcat.

Hope this will help someone else,
Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem when deploying an .EAR on Weblogic 10.3.5. It was caused by the JAXB v.2.1.13 implementation included in the  deployment package, whereas weblogic already provides v.2.1.14. It even affected the order of the .EARs we deploy.
When I removed the 2 copies of JAXB v.2.1.13 from the deployment directory (package), it deployed correctly both as first or last in the order of deployment.

The problem method seems to be com.sun.xml.txw2.TXW.getTagName(Class) which (in)correctly recognizes the XMLNamespace annotation of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema package.

Hope this helps.